# how to calculate current location change by 10 meters?

Tags: google-maps, flutter, dart, geolocation, latitude-longitude

How to calculate current location change by 10 meters? 10 meters is dynamically changed.

I tried, `location` plugin on Flutter. but not working curretly.

`location.changeSettings(distanceFilter: 10,interval: 1000);` //10 is meters, but location is updating every time.

How to calculate like this, I need to know how to calculate.(Because I need to calculate waiting time when travelling)

**if(currentLocation > previousLocation) // currentLocation should be greater than 10 meters**

```
currentLication = previousLocation + 10 meters
```

Comment: Sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 2):

I don't think location plugin provide such functionality at this time, But you can use `onLocationChanged` callback event

```
location.onLocationChanged().listen((LocationData currentLocation) {
  // Use current location
});
```

It will return you current location, than you have to calculate it by using Haversine formula, see more details [here](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928/calculate-distance-between-two-latitude-longitude-points-haversine-formula/59646977#59646977)

```
a = sin²(Δφ/2) + cos φ1 ⋅ cos φ2 ⋅ sin²(Δλ/2)
c = 2 ⋅ atan2( √a, √(1−a) )
d = R ⋅ c
```

below [dart code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59646977/969068) can help you to calculate difference and get next location:

```
import 'dart:math' show cos, sqrt, asin;

double calculateDistance(LatLng l1, LatLng l2) {
  const p = 0.017453292519943295;
  final a = 0.5 -
      cos((l2.latitude - l1.latitude) * p) / 2 +
      cos(l1.latitude * p) *
          cos(l2.latitude * p) *
          (1 - cos((l2.longitude - l1.longitude) * p)) /
          2;
  return 12742 * asin(sqrt(a));
}
```

Comment: what is the return type value? KM or meter?KM right?

Comment: `return 1000 * 12742 * asin(sqrt(a));` Is it now meter right?

Comment: it returns in km,  yes